# How to get outputs with specific names

Tags: perl, output

I'm trying to edit some text files at once with perl. So I have a folder "input" where I put my input text files, and I have a folder "output" where I get the text files edited. So my script starts like (I only copy the beginning):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

opendir IN, 'input';
my @in = grep { /^[^.]/ } readdir IN;
closedir IN;

for my $in (@in) {
open IN, '<', "input/$in" || next;
open OUT, '>', "output/$in" || die "can't open file output/$in";
```

My input text files are named TH0001_file.txt, TH0002_file.txt, ...
I would want that my output text files be named TH0001_edited.txt, TH0002_edited.txt, ....

But I do not know how to edit my perl to get that. Of course, I can use the "rename" command once I get the output to rename my files, but I would like to know how to do that in perl. Someone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following code as a starting point:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

foreach my $in_file (<input/*.txt>) {
    print "input file name: $in_file\n";
    if ($in_file =~ m/\/([^_]+)_file.txt$/) {
        my $out_file = "output/$1_edited.txt";
        print "output file name: $out_file\n";
    }
}
```